# How to access public html directory in Cpanel

Tags: node.js, file-upload, upload, cpanel, multer

I trying to save a image via a post upload rest api deployed in nodejs app Cpanel.
But I get an error:
No such file or directory /home/xxx/public_html/assets

The folder already exists

Library used : multer

Tutorial used:
[here](https://omarshishani.com/2020/12/15/how-to-upload-images-to-server-with-react-and-express/&ved=2ahUKEwjfm8zbpeXzAhUIqZUCHZvLCm4QFnoECDAQAQ&sqi=2&usg=AOvVaw35J0ur9iK9wDHmFEHWXRDA)

The upload working fine in local.
I think that the nodejs Cpanel app is contained..